TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object how can ı solve this problem
from .colour_segmentation import segment_lanes
from ...config import config
from .midlane_estimation import estimate_midlane
import cv2
import numpy as np
from .data_extraction import FetchInfoAndDisplay
from .cleaning import GetYellowInnerEdge, ExtendShortLane


# this is my lane_detection file
def detect_lanes(img):
    
    img_cropped = img[config.CropHeight_resized:,:]

    mid_lane_mask, mid_lane_edge,outer_lane_edge, outerlane_side_sep,outerlane_points = segment_lanes(img_cropped,config.minArea_resized)

    estimated_midlane = estimate_midlane(mid_lane_edge,config.MaxDist_resized)

    OuterLane_OneSide, Outer_cnts_oneSide,Mid_cnts, Offset_correction  = GetYellowInnerEdge(outer_lane_edge, estimated_midlane, outerlane_points)

    extended_midlane, extended_outerlane = ExtendShortLane(estimated_midlane,Mid_cnts,Outer_cnts_oneSide, OuterLane_OneSide)
    
    Distance , Curvature = FetchInfoAndDisplay(mid_lane_edge, extended_midlane, extended_outerlane, img_cropped, Offset_correction=Offset_correction)


    

    cv2.imshow("mid_lane_mask", mid_lane_mask)
    cv2.imshow("mid_lane_edge", mid_lane_edge)
    cv2.imshow("outer_lane_edge", outer_lane_edge)
    cv2.imshow("outerlane_side_sep", outerlane_side_sep)
    cv2.imshow("estimated_midlane", estimated_midlane)

    cv2.imshow("OuterLane_OneSide", OuterLane_OneSide)
    cv2.imshow("extended_midlane", extended_midlane)
    cv2.imshow("extended_outerlane", extended_outerlane)

    cv2.waitKey(1)

and this is my func
def ExtendShortLane(MidLane,Mid_cnts,Outer_cnts,OuterLane):
    if(Mid_cnts and Outer_cnts):
        Mid_cnts_Rowsorted = Cord_Sort(Mid_cnts,"rows")
        Outer_cnts_Rowsorted = Cord_Sort(Outer_cnts,"rows")
        Image_bottom = MidLane.shape[0]
        total_no_of_cnts_midlane = Mid_cnts_Rowsorted.shape[0]
        total_no_of_cnts_outerlane = Outer_cnts_Rowsorted.shape[0]


        BottomPoint_Mid = Mid_cnts_Rowsorted[total_no_of_cnts_midlane-1,:]
        if (BottomPoint_Mid[1] < Image_bottom):
            MidLane = cv2.line(MidLane,tuple(BottomPoint_Mid),(BottomPoint_Mid[0],Image_bottom),255,2)


        BottomPoint_Outer = Outer_cnts_Rowsorted[total_no_of_cnts_outerlane-1,:]
        if (BottomPoint_Outer[1] < Image_bottom):
            if(total_no_of_cnts_outerlane>20):
                shift=20
            else:
                shift=2
            RefLast10Points = Outer_cnts_Rowsorted[total_no_of_cnts_outerlane-shift:total_no_of_cnts_outerlane] 

            if(len(RefLast10Points)>1):
                Ref_x = RefLast10Points[:,0] #cols
                Ref_y = RefLast10Points[:,1] #rows
                Ref_parameters = np.polyfit(Ref_x, Ref_y,1)
                Ref_slope = Ref_parameters[0]
                Ref_yiCntercept = Ref_parameters[1]

                if(Ref_slope < 0):
                    Ref_LineTouchPoint_col = 0
                    Ref_LineTouchPoint_row = Ref_yiCntercept
                else:
                    Ref_LineTouchPoint_col = OuterLane.shape[1]-1
                    Ref_LineTouchPoint_row = Ref_slope * Ref_LineTouchPoint_col + Ref_yiCntercept
                Ref_TouchPoint = (Ref_LineTouchPoint_col,int(Ref_LineTouchPoint_row))#col,row
                Ref_BottomPoint_tup = tuple(BottomPoint_Outer)
                OuterLane =cv2.line(OuterLane,Ref_TouchPoint,Ref_BottomPoint_tup,255)
                 
                if(Ref_LineTouchPoint_row < Image_bottom):
                    Ref_TouchPoint_Ref = (Ref_LineTouchPoint_col, Image_bottom)     
                    OuterLane = cv2.line(OuterLane,Ref_TouchPoint,Ref_TouchPoint_Ref,255,2)      
        return MidLane,OuterLane

why it is return None

lane assist. please help me

this error that ı got                                                                                               File "/home/mina/udemy_ws/install/self_driving_car_pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/self_driving_car_pkg/Detection/Lanes/lane_detection.py", line 21, in detect_lanes
extended_midlane, extended_outerlane = ExtendShortLane(estimated_midlane,Mid_cnts,Outer_cnts_oneSide, OuterLane_OneSide)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

[tour], [ask], [mre]

Quick feedback - you have a meaningful return statement only in a certain condition. If this condition isn't meant, the function implicitly returns None. Think about what you should return in the other branches.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Your function returns values only if the if(Mid_cnts and Outer_cnts): condition is satisfied. Otherwise it returns None
I suspect you either forgot to write the else block for that condition, or the return instruction should be out of the if block

thanks for your help ^^ Yes return was not in the right place
